# How to use wildcards in message filters in Outlook 2010

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, email-filter

I want to set up a filter who moves every email which includes following header

```
X-Facebook : from zuckmail
X-Facebook : XXXXfrom zuckmailXXXX
X-Facebook : YYYYfrom zuckmailYYYY
```

and so on.
normally I would set something like

```
X-Facebook : *from zuckmail*
```

Answer (score 1):

Using wildcard characters in message rules is not supported unfortunately.

You could create a solution by writing a VBA script though.

First you would create a rule based on the condition 'With specific words in the message header'. Then if the headers contains `X-Facebook`, run the VBA script.

The script would then check the headers further, and do the wildcard expression matching. If it matches, it would then move the mail item to the specific folder.